# Open html link in new window with no browser toolbars

Tags: javascript, html

I know that I can open html links in a new window by using target="_blank", but
how can I hide/disable all the browser toolbars ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `window.open('url to open','window name','toolbar=no');`

Comment: Remeber that users can force their browser to always show toolbars and status bars.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open('your url here','name','toolbar=0,status=0');
```

With Javascript. But it's better and usable, if you create a fake window with javascript.

Comment: Why is a fake window always better?  Some users (e.g. me) like to able to bookmark popups, if they're actually useful.

Comment: @Matthew: imo its a design error to communicate such an information in a popup that is worth to bookmark.
A popup shows a status of a process to the user or gives some informations, but its not a whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the only way to do that is to use the JavaScript Window.open function. I don't know of any HTML/CSS-only way of hiding browser controls.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Seriously. It's one of the better ways to drive away users.

Comment: I would usually agree with you, but I have a genuine requirement to do it!

Comment: I agree with this sentiment in principle, but there are good reasons to do this in the right context. For example in a web application where you need to maximize screen real estate. But, for a typical website, this is not a good idea.