# Window opens with toolbar even when using toolbar=no

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm working on an app that uses this to open the homepage of the application after they have successfully entered the login details:

```
window.open("app_homepage_url","myApp","toolbar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=no,location=no,menubar=no,directories=no");
```

This normally works as expected and hides the toolbar but one user has reported that they still have the toolbar showing. They are using Internet Explorer.

My first thought was maybe there's already a window open with the name 'myApp' and the toolbar shown so the homepage is getting loaded into that window instead of a new one but I tried doing that and the application does not let you log in due to the way the login is handled with sessions so I don't think it can be that.

The comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954528/open-html-link-in-new-window-with-no-browser-toolbars/954540#954540) seems to suggest there is a way to force the browser to always show the toolbar so I wonder if it is to do with this. Does anyone know how you actually do this?

Any other ideas?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542721/window-open-location-no-does-not-work/1542748

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a browser configuration issue.
Have a test on the following configuration settings on IE7 and IE8:

1. Goto Tools->Internet Options->Security Tab
2. Select an appropriate security zone settings
3. Click on Custom level.. button
4. On the settings tab, look for Miscellaneous Node
5. Then have a test on the following settings
   Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraint
   All websites to open windows without address or status bar.

Closing the browser might helpful when changing configuration settings.

Comment: Didn't know about those settings. I'll give that a try.