# How to open a window without toolbars and addressbar?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to open ( via javascript ) a new window but without toolbar, addressbar, etc ?

I have tested this code:

```
window.open('http://example.it','example','height=300px,width=724px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1,location=1,links=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0');
```

but in Opera, it shows the bookmarks bar and the address bar.

Comment: I hate those kinds of windows. They're ugly and annoying. You should have a very good reason for making a popup. Consider using a dialog instead.

Comment: I am designing a bookmarklet, so it will be not annoying.

Comment: It most probably will.  See the printliminator by Chris Coyer, he's doing it rather nicely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open html link in new window with no browser toolbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954528/open-html-link-in-new-window-with-no-browser-toolbars)

Answer (score 1):

Opera doesn't support hiding the bookmark or address bar. Here is [one site](http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html) that documents this, although it look old. A quick search brings up a lot of browser quirks with window.open(), and unfortunately, there probably aren't any workarounds since opening a window a certain way is strictly controlled by the browser.

**Edit:** I just found a page on the site I posted that says "Last update: April 28th 2012", so maybe the tacky old 90s look is just for fun.

Comment: I also configure Firefox to ignore attempts to hide the address bar, the menus, etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's not a great idea to open new windows with JavaScript, but I wanted to answer the question thoroughly too.

Comment: I am designing a bookmarklet, so I need to remove the addressbar and toolbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, Opera isn't going to let you do it. The best solution may be to submit a bug report to Opera (https://bugs.opera.com/wizarddesktop/). In the mean time, you will have to live with the toolbar and address bar. Only a small percentage of people use Opera anyway, and they are probably used to its quirks.